# Watch window.scrollY changes in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very simple app, that has 2 components: the `App.vue` and another component, `Home.vue` where I hold the rest of the structure of the app: a sticky header and some sections with anchors to scroll to.

I want to apply a class to the sticky header to minimize the logo while the page is scrolled. So I thought I'd watch for any changes in `window.scrollY`. So if `scrollY` is greater than 0, apply some class that minimizes the logo.

I tried to listen to scroll events in my component, but that didn't go very far. In this discussion here, a very good solution is provided, but I don't know where to place the scroll event. https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/324

So, I thought the most fitting solution would be to create a data property, assign it the `window.scrollY` figure and then watch for changes in its value. Unfortunately, the watcher is never triggered. So now I'm stuck. The code is:

```
data () {
return {
  ...
  windowTop: window.top.scrollY
 }
}
...
watch: {
 windowTop: {
  immediate: true,
  handler (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
  },
 }
}
```

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`window` properties can't be used reactively like that. Instead, you'd have to listen to the `window`'s `scroll` event and respond accordingly:

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll)
},
beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll)
},
methods: {
  onScroll(e) {
    this.windowTop = window.top.scrollY /* or: e.target.documentElement.scrollTop */
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Watching scrollTop in Vue]

Answer (score 13):

For me none of the above worked.

I had to pass `true` as 3rd parameter in add/remove scroll listener:

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll, true)
},
beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll, true)
},
methods: {
  onScroll(e) {
    this.windowTop = e.target.scrollTop;
  }
}
```

3rd parameter:
You should be able to attach a document-level listener with a third parameter of true to capture the scroll events on all elements. Here's what that looks like:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){ }, true);
```

The true at the end is the important part, it tells the browser to capture the event on dispatch, even if that event does not normally bubble, like change, focus, and scroll.

Answer (score 5):

2020 Updated:

Use `@scroll.passive` to watch scroll of any element in component:

Example:

Template

```
<div class="room_message-stream" @scroll.passive="handleScroll">
      <ul class="room_message-stream__list">
        <li class="room_message-stream__list-item">...</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Methods:

```
handleScroll (e) {
  var scrollPos = e.target.scrollTop
}
```

Comment: `scroll` events can't be `preventDefault`ed, so the `passive` flag won't help here. The flag is typically used to [improve scrolling performance](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners) for expensive `touchstart`/`touchmove` event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mounted()` method to add your event listener to the window object like this:

```js
var p = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data(){
      return {
          windowTop: 0
      };
   },
   mounted()
   {
       var that = this;
       window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
           that.windowTop = window.scrollY;
       });
   },
   template: "<div style='height: 250vh'><div style='position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0'>{{windowTop}}</div></div>"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something where I just have to call a variable or function to get the window scroll position in any component. So in order to achieve that I end up using mixins.
Here is my code. I am using nuxt.

Inside plugin create a file eg. scroll-position.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.mixin({
    data() {
        return {
            scrollPosition: window.scrollY
        }
    },
    methods: {
        get_scroll_position() {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
            });
            return this.scrollPosition
        }
    }
})
```

In nuxt.config.js

```
plugins:['@/plugins/scroll-position.js']
```

Now you can use get_scroll_position() in any component you want
Something like this

```
:class="{'header_sticky':get_scroll_position()>=80}"
```

Comment: **Warning:** This introduces a memory leak. `get_scroll_position()` adds a new event listener on every call. And since this is bound in the template, every time the component renders (which can be multiple times on a page), a new event listener is added to the `window` unnecessarily.