# How to pass dynamic mouse-scroll value as a prop in VueJS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel - VueJS framework.

I want to detect a Y position of the mouse-scroll and pass it dynamically as a prop to a component Navbar. For this, I created an eventListener and stored the window.scrollY value to a variable scrollPos inside data(). After this I pass scrollPos as a prop to the Navbar component use v-bind:scrollPos="scrollPos". Unfortunately, the value that's passed in the Navbar component is just 0, and does not change on any further mouse scrolling.

```
<Navbar v-on:scroll="this.changeScrollPos" v-bind:scrollPos="scrollPos" />

mounted() {

        console.log('Component mounted.');
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
                this.scrollPos = window.scrollY;
                console.log(this.scrollPos);
        });

},
data() {
    return {
        scrollPos: 0
    }
}, 
methods: {
    changeScrollPos() {
        console.log('Mouse scrolled');
    }
}
```

I pass the value into the Navbar component, where I simply want to display this value in the navigation bar, that is fixed to the top of the page and that has router-links that scroll to that section of the page when clicked.

```
<nav class="nav" id="nav">
    <div class="nav-content>
        <ul class="nav-items">
            <li class="nav-item"><router-link to="/" v-scroll-to="'#section1'">{{ scrollPos }}</router-link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            "scrollPos"
        ]
    }
</script>
```

I also tried to use `v-on:scroll="this.changeScrollPos()"` method to check whether this method is accessed after any changes in mouse scroll, but it does not.

Can someone explain why this does not work and help me out in passing dynamic mouse scroll values to the Navbar component.

Edit: This is similar to [Watch window.scrollY changes in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391472/watch-window-scrolly-changes-in-vuejs) but not the issue in this problem is already resolved and I can extract the value of mouse-scroll and display it, my issue is I want to pass this value to the component and when this value changes, the value passed to the component should also change (Dynamic value getting passed real-time, based on the mouse-scroll).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watch window.scrollY changes in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391472/watch-window-scrolly-changes-in-vuejs)

Comment: Edited my question, I am able to extract the value of the mouse scroll (as was the issue pointed out in that question). I want to pass this value to my component and when this value changes, I want to also change the value being passed to the component.

Comment: `this.scrollPos = window.scrollY;` here `this` is not the Vue instance because you don't use arrow function.

Comment: Can you share how you pass the data to the component and how you use it inside?

Comment: I tried to refer the variable without using `this` but it gave an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollPos is not defined`
Also added additional code for the component where the scrollPos value is passed. In the main page, I am passing the value through `v-bind:scrollPos="scrollPos"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is not Vue related, it is a general javascript `this` function context.

Inside a regular function, the value of this depends on how the function was called ([See this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for a detailed explanation). In your case, the `this` inside of the callback passed to the addEventListener function will be undefined, because it was just simply defined as a regular function and not bound to anything specific.

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    this.scrollPos = window.scrollY; // this in here is undefined 
  });
}
```

If you want `this` to point to the vue instance while using a regular function, you can play with the variable scope like this:

```
mounted() {
  const THIS = this; // this points to the vue instance and we pass a 
                     // reference to the THIS variable
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    THIS.scrollPos = window.scrollY; // THIS here points to the vue instance
  });
}
```

This last method is what we traditionally used to achieve that prior to ES6. After ES6, with the inclusion of the fat arrow function, we were able to do it in an easier fashion (as you already found out) because the fat arrow function doesn't bind the this variable:

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', e => this.scrollPos = window.scrollY);
}
```

As you can see, it's a much cleaner syntax and that's why we prefer it now. Just beware that IE11 and below don't support arrow functions so you'll need to use a pre-compiler like babel (But I guess you're already using it)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I am starting to understand how arrow functions work now.

Answer (score 0):

As Slim pointed out, I converted my function into an arrow function and now it works. I still didn't understand why this change made it work, would be really helpful if someone explains it.

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll, () => { this.scrollPos = window.scrollY; });
}
```